# Prevent external users to connect websocket (wss)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a react-nodejs website at https://example.com and it utilizes websocket (using [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) library), but right now people can just **npm install socket.io-client** and connect to my websocket using this:

```
const {io} = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("wss://example.com");
```

Now they can emit/listen to my backend. At the moment, I use ReCAPTCHA to prevent bots so you need to pass a token to connect to the socket.io server, I was wondering whether there is a better solution than this.

Comment: when your client connect to a there will be a connection token generated by socket.io. you can store it on server-side for emitting and listen to event.  use socket connect in both side by using token and user-id

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you can't prevent people from trying to connect to your socket.io server manually with a custom script using `socket.io-client`. Normally that's a reason for you to design the server in a way, that connected client sockets can't do any harm. Client sockets are usually on the receiving side.

But of course there is a best-practice on how to authenticate the connecting clients, and, if the authentication is failing, to prevent the connection. Checkout out the [socket.io Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#auth) about `client options`. There is an `auth` field available :

*Client*

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token: "abcd"
  }
});
```

*Server*

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.handshake.auth); // prints { token: "abcd" }
});
```

So once the user is logged in, use the JWT (Token) (assuming you having a JWT Authentication in place) and pass it during establishing the connection. Then validate the JWT on the server side.

#### client-certificate authentication

There is also [a more advanced](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#nodejs-specific-options) option for client authentication which uses certificates:

*Client*

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("https://example.com", {
  ca: fs.readFileSync("./server-cert.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./client-cert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./client-key.pem"),
});
```

*Server*

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const server = require("https").createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./server-cert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync("./server-key.pem"),
  requestCert: true,
  ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem')
  ]
});
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

Comment: For JWT, I believe they are stored on browser storage (e.g. localstorage), this means that the attacker can just copy paste the token from the browser and pass it to connect socket.io server right?
I will look forward to the client-certificate authentication.

Comment: Does not necessarily need to be stored in local storage. That's up to you. It's often the case that JWT are stored in local storage, so they can be used for later in proceeding API Calls. But to authenticate a socket.io connection it would only be used once. Also you could implement an expiration time to the JWT to something low like a couple of seconds. After that the JWT expires. Also this would mean, the attacker needs access to the users browser.

Comment: Again, I would always account for the case, that some user might connect to your socket.io server unauthorized and manually ... socket.io is a well-known library . So even if this person connects to your server, what harm could it do ?

Comment: Ohh, so before connecting the socket.io, the client should fetch a JWT token using REST API or something right? But can the attacker also fetch a token externally? Or if there is another method to get the token please let me know :). You can say my website is like "agar.io" where you collect points and ranked on the leaderboard, I have implemented a clamping mechanism (only 50 points/sec is allowed), but it just bothers me that people can just socket.emit("x", { points: 50}) instead of getting the points as intended.

Comment: So yes, normally a JWT is fetched using a REST endpoint ... but cases I am thinking of involves at least a password and a username.